# CSS Transition Delay on border bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-transitions

I have a traditional ecommerce filter list below. You have can click to filter products by attributes like shoesize, vendor, etc if your buying shoes.

My problem has to do with borders. I have every element set to `border:bottom`. **Look at what the line below "Puma" is doing when you click sample code below.**

[image]

```js
const headings = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.refine__heading'));
const contents = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.refine__content'));
headings.forEach(heading => heading.addEventListener('click', addCollapsed));

function addCollapsed(e){
  e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('collapsed');
}
```

```css
/* Reset */
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
/* Actual Notes */
.refine {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.refine__heading {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dadbd9;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.refine__content {
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 3s ease-out;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dadbd9; /* important */
}
.refine label {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.collapsed {
  max-height: 0px;
  border-bottom: none; /* important */
  transition-delay: border-bottom 3s; /* I CANT FIGURE THIS PART OUT*/
  transition: max-height 3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css">

<ul class="refine">
  <li class="refine__section">
    <div class="refine__heading"><span class="refine__heading-content">Vendors</span><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></div>
    <div class="refine__content">
      <label><span class="refine__item">Nike</span><span class="count">4</span></label>
      <label><span class="refine__item">Adidas</span><span class="count">5</span></label>
      <label><span class="refine__item">Puma</span><span class="count">6</span></label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="refine__section">
    <div class="refine__heading"><span class="refine__heading-content">Shoe Size</span><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></div>
    <div class="refine__content">
      <label><span class="refine__item">Large</span><span class="count">4</span></label>
      <label><span class="refine__item">Medium</span><span class="count">5</span></label>
      <label><span class="refine__item">Small</span><span class="count">6</span></label>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT** I made the transitions from 0.5 second to 3 seconds so you can see it easier

Comment: I don't see anything happening to the line. Can you please explain a bit more clearly what your problem is?

Comment: the line below puma should stay visible until it merges with the next line, when you toggle collapse. It doesn't right now

Comment: Its a very short transition of 0.5 seconds I will edit to make it last longer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two main problems:
First, your `transition-delay` value only takes time - no CSS property names.
Second, your `border-bottom` cannot be transitioned from `none`.

Here's one way of doing things:

```js
const headings = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.refine__heading'));
const contents = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.refine__content'));
headings.forEach(heading => heading.addEventListener('click', addCollapsed));

function addCollapsed(e){
  e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('collapsed');
}
```

```css
/* Reset */
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
/* Actual Notes */
.refine {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.refine__heading {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dadbd9;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.refine__content {
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease-out;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dadbd9; /* important */
}
.refine label {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.collapsed {
  max-height: 0px;

  /* CHANGED FROM HERE DOWN */
  border-bottom-width: 0; /* important */
  transition-property: max-height, border-bottom-width;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-delay: 0, 2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css">

<ul class="refine">
  <li class="refine__section">
    <div class="refine__heading"><span class="refine__heading-content">Vendors</span><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></div>
    <div class="refine__content">
      <label><span class="refine__item">Nike</span><span class="count">4</span></label>
      <label><span class="refine__item">Adidas</span><span class="count">5</span></label>
      <label><span class="refine__item">Puma</span><span class="count">6</span></label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="refine__section">
    <div class="refine__heading"><span class="refine__heading-content">Shoe Size</span><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></div>
    <div class="refine__content">
      <label><span class="refine__item">Large</span><span class="count">4</span></label>
      <label><span class="refine__item">Medium</span><span class="count">5</span></label>
      <label><span class="refine__item">Small</span><span class="count">6</span></label>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks this works perfectly. Could you elaborate how this works though?

Comment: Sure can! I just broke the `transition` short-hand into separate CSS properties to be easier to handle. The multiple transition properties are equivalent to `transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out 0, border-bottom-width 0.3s ease-out 2s;`. Is that helpful?

Comment: Here's an additional resource that may help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

Comment: Its helpful but is there a way to breakdown something like this `transition-property: max-height, border-bottom-width;` and this `transition-delay: 0, 2s;` into seperate lines? I'm getting confused which transitions are applying to which items (max height, border bottom width)

Comment: Aside from what I showed in my first comment above, I don't believe so. You could, however, use that format and add line breaks between the commas if it helps. Just note that you will have some duplication this way. Here's a fiddle to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/xsybe5c9/9/

Answer (score 1):

transition delay doesn't take an attribute. you need to set up a different class for the border-bottom like this:

```
.hide-border-bottom{
  transition: border-bottom 0.3s ease-out;
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}
```

and add the class to the addCollapsed function like you did .collapsed